# $watch fired only on second update of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a directive in my angularJS module that integrates a custom jQuery control. The control is a slider and is created only when a global variable `$rootScope.vm` is modified. The slider has a release function and on that function (the lower/upper bounds can be changed) I want to modify 2 properties of `$rootScope.vm` and broadcast this change with a `$rootScope.$watch` call so a controller can process this change.

The problem is that when I change the slider position it enters the release function, changes the values of `$rootScope.vm` but then stops at the broadcast. If I click it again then the broadcast is fired. I would like to know why this is happening and what can I do so that the broadcast will be fired the first time (to note: I have tried to put the `true` for objectEquality but that doesn't fix the problem)

Broadcast code:

```
service.updateGlobalMileageFromModule = function (start, end) {
        console.log("Inside broadcast function");
        if (!this.vm) {
            this.vm = {};
        }
       this.vm.MileageStart = start;
        this.vm.MileageEnd = end;
        $rootScope.$broadcast("GlobalMileageFromModuleUpdated");        
    };
```

Angular directive:

```
    .directive('slider', function ($rootScope, BroadCastGlobalData) {
    var min, max, minPos, maxPos;
    var updateSliderRange = true;
    var releaseFunction = function (min, max) {
        console.log("Inside release function");
        $rootScope.vm.MileageStart = min;
        $rootScope.vm.MileageEnd = max;
        $rootScope.$apply();
        $rootScope.$watch('vm', function () {
            console.log("Inside $watch function");
            if ($rootScope.vm.MileageEnd != 0 && $rootScope.value.MileageStart != 0) {
                BroadCastGlobalData.updateGlobalMileageFromModule($rootScope.vm.MileageStart, $rootScope.vm.MileageEnd);
                updateSliderRange = false;
            }
        });
    };    
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<div></div',
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            $rootScope.$on('GlobalMileageFromControllerUpdated', function () {
                //somehow limit this to only the first call on the facet load.
                if (updateSliderRange)
                {
                    min = BroadCastGlobalData.vm.MileageStart;
                    max = BroadCastGlobalData.vm.MileageEnd;
                }
                //this should be updated everytime the slider hands move.
                minPos = BroadCastGlobalData.vm.MileageStart;
                maxPos = BroadCastGlobalData.vm.MileageEnd;
                var slider = new range_slider({
                    selector: '.range-slider',
                    unit: ' miles',
                    min: min,
                    max: max,
                    left_scrubber_pos: minPos,
                    right_scrubber_pos: maxPos,
                    round_by: 1000,
                    rounded: true,
                    // Event during initialization
                    release: function (e) {
                        console.log("Slider released at positions: " + e.min + ", " + e.max);
                        //broadcast data changed. capture data in controller. make call to server for refreshed data.                        
                        releaseFunction(e.min, e.max);
                        //console.log("Event happened, this object contains: \n\n { \n min : " + e.min + ",\nmax : " + e.max + "\n}");
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
})
```

As a side note, I'm working in ASP.NET MVC4

Comment: Move the watch outside releaseFunction.

Comment: If I move the watch outside the release function the watch is never getting called...

Comment: a fiddle would be helpful.

Comment: alright, try passing `true` as the 3rd parameter to watch..after the function ends `},true);`

Comment: I've tried passing true as the 3rd parameter. The same things happens. I can't make a fiddle for you, but I can put the whole directive code in here. Maybe you'll get a better perspective.

Comment: Try moving the watch outside the directive to the place where you have defined `$rootScope.vm`.

Comment: `$rootScope.vm` if defined in the `.run()` of the module. Is it OK to move it there? EDIT: Same thing happens, the `$watch` isn't triggered at all.

Comment: The problem in my opinion is that the watch is registered only after the release function is called for the first time.

Comment: Try moving `$rootScope.$apply();` after the watch, at the bottom.

Comment: But that would mean that the slider should update at the first release after this glitch. But it doesn't. Every time I want to update the slider I have to double click it.

Comment: Same thing if I move the `$rootScope.apply()` after the `$watch()`.